# mhddfs filesystem hangs after a while with large directory

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount, raid

I have 2 RAID1 of 4TB each which are joined together with mhddfs. There is one directory that exists on both disks that contains hundreds of thousands of files. There is a lot of read/write happening in that directory but sometimes, and I can't figure out why, it stops working.

Whatever process that was writing will "hang" and from there, nothing can be written to that directory unless I unmount the mhddfs file system and remount it. I can write to other directories. I can write to the directory that's stuck on each separate drive, just not on the mhddfs one.

I'm not sure what could be causing this and I'm not sure how to debug it either. There isn't a whole lot of information about mhddfs that I could find online.